# Register a module theme implementations

Tags: 7, theming

I have created a simple module to display frequently asked questions (FAQ). The output (faq content) can be customize in mymodule-template.tpl.php file located in a module directory.

I'd like to create an additional template file suggestion for the theme directory e.g: sites/all/themes/mytheme/templates/mymodule-template.tpl.php

So, the main goal is to add two template file suggestions.

1. [my module path]/mymodule-template.tpl.php
2. [active theme path]/templates/mymodule-template.tpl.php

To achieve #1 I have implemented this hook.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme()
 * @return
 *  An array with the name of template file and variables
 */
function simple_faq_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
    // get faq content
    $records     = get_faq_content();   // categories, questions, answers
    $description = get_faq_info('intro');   // faq description

    return array(
        'faq_template'  => array(
          'template'    => 'simple_faq',
          'variables'   => array('records' => $records, 'description' => $description),
        )
    );
}


/**
 * FAQ Page content
 *
 * @return
 *  HTML created by template file
 */ 
function simple_faq_page() {
    return theme('faq_template');
}
```

It works, but I can't figure out how to create an additional suggestion, which allows users to theme the output without changing anything within module files.

Any idea?

Comment: So your template file is simple_faq.tpl.php? It should works out of the box, try to copy this file to theme directory. To add suggestions, use `template_preprocess_faq_template(&$variables)` and add it there like `$variables['theme_hook_suggestions'] = array('simple_faq__' . current_path());`

Comment: Yes, and it works, but is there any way to do that in module? without preprocess functions?

Comment: This function should be in your module if You want provide template suggestions, like any other modules do, look eg. to field, node, etc., all of these have function `template_preprocess_theme`

Comment: Copy your `simple_faq.tpl.php` file to current theme's templates folder and it should work.

Comment: @malcolm - template_preprocess function did what I needs. It works, but unfortunately I've got stuck again.. I have my new suggestion file name (simple_fag_faq) in theme_hook_suggestions array, but the output is still generated by the default template file (simple_fag). Any idea what's missing?

Comment: Can be filename problem. When you add `simple_fag_faq` your template file should be `simple-fag-faq`.

Comment: yes, suggestion is: simple_fag__faq so the filename should be: simple-faq--faq.tpl.php - I've tried with underscores as well, but with no results. Well, at least I'm on the right way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your hook_theme implementation is not being done in the usual way.
It should only have default values for the variables, like this:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme()
 * @return
 *  An array with the name of template file and variables
 */
function simple_faq_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array(
    'faq_template' => array(
      'template' => 'simple_faq',
      'variables' => array('records' => array(), 'description' => ''),
    )
  );
}
```

Then when you call the theme function is where you send the actual values in, like this:

```
/**
 * FAQ Page content
 *
 * @return
 *  HTML created by template file
 */ 
 function simple_faq_page() {
   // Get faq content.
   // Categories, questions, answers.
   $records = get_faq_content();
   // faq description.
   $description = get_faq_info('intro');
   return theme('faq_template', array('records' => $records, 'description' => $description));
 }
```

As far as I know you can't give 2 values for the template file, however what you want to do should already be possible.
All you have to do is tell it where the original template file is in your module, then drupal will automatically find ones that are in any themes (the defining module doesn't have to set up anything for the theme).

Comment: I've tried to learn why the variables defined in hook_theme() should contain only default NULL values, but I haven't found any explanation about that. I tried to define them once, in hook_theme(), and they works, however, it seems the right way to do that is exactly like you wrote. Thank you very much.

Comment: The reason is that they are just default values that are used in the case that no value is passed in when calling theme(). If these default values weren't there then there would be lots of undefined index/variable errors if you omitted any variables when calling theme(). This means that theme functions don't need to check for the existence of the variable, they can just rely on the fact it will be there, even if it is just the default value.